# Does the Undetectable Extension Charm negate the weight of the objects put into the container?

Tags: harry-potter

The main example of the charm is Hermione's bag in the seventh book, in which she stores several items and carries it around effortlessly.

This leads me to the question, does the charm itself negate the weight of the objects in her bag, or is there a need for other charms/spells for that purpose?

Comment: Being the perfectionist she is, do you really think Hermione would skip leg day? ;-)

Comment: Harry mentions a charm to make his trunk featherlight in PoA. So we do know there is such a charm (and if Harry knows it Hermione definitely does)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/extension-charms):

> Hogwarts school trunks, like the majority of wizarding luggage, are issued with capacity enhancing or extension charms as standard. These spells not only increase the interior dimensions of objects, while leaving the outer ones unchanged, **they also render the contents lighter**.
>
> <sub><sup>[Extension Charms By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/extension-charms)</sup></sub>

So yes, the charm does indeed negate the weight of the objects put inside

Answer (score 12):

## It probably did - she doesn't mention using any other spells on it.

When she tells Harry how she enchanted the bag to carry everything they needed, she only mentioned casting the Undetectable Extension Charm. She doesn't mention any other spells to make it easier to carry, and it's unlike her to partially describe her methods.

> “Undetectable Extension Charm,’ said Hermione. ‘Tricky, but I think I’ve done it OK; anyway, I managed to fit everything we need in here.’ She gave the fragile-looking bag a little shake and it echoed like a cargo hold as a number of heavy objects rolled around inside it. ‘Oh, damn, that’ll be the books,’ she said, peering into it, ‘and I had them all stacked by subject … oh well … Harry, you’d better take the Invisibility Cloak. Ron, hurry up and change …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 9 (A Place to Hide)*</sup></sub>

It is possible that she used another spell on her bag to make its content lighter, but it seems more likely that she fully described what she did, and it was a effect of the Undetectable Extension Charm.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Hermione might have some additional spells she really doesn't need. for example;hermione added extra spells in the deathly hallows to protect their tent from death eaters.

Comment: @TheCoolChameleon Yes, it's possible - but she never mentioned using any, and since she usually describes what she does thoroughly, it's unlikely she partially described what she did with the bag.

Answer (score 1):

Definately negates weight - if it didn't, you'd be able to *detect* the objects inside (or at least some aspect of their existence)

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site.